# Is it possible to have a spring boot app ran as init.d service and use an external script?

Tags: spring-boot, web-deployment, init.d

Is it possible to have a spring boot app ran as init.d service and use an external script?
In this external script I want to define some system properties. And I need the script to be external.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. You just need to create a `symlink` from `init.d` directory to your spring-boot jar.
According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) you can define system properties in `.conf` file which is located next to the jar file and has the same name.